# Does a Polearm Master with 10' reach get an opportunity attack vs an enemy 10' away when they step to only 5' away?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack, reach

Polearm Master states:

> While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter the reach you have with that weapon.

So if you are wielding a weapon with 10' reach and an enemy starts their turn 10' away, do they provoke the opportunity attack when they move closer to only 5' away?

Comment: If this is something you want to make happen for your character, check out the Unearthed Arcana: Light, Dark, Underdark. There is a fighting style called Tunnel Fighter that allows this. It never made it into something official, but you could always ask your DM.

Comment: @Shadomew It was never published because it was horribly broken.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov From personal experience, I know how broken it is. Sometimes DMs will let players have powerful items/features because it's fun to be powerful, so there's no harm in OP asking their DM about it.

Comment: This was the case in 3.5, where you would also trigger an opportunity attack by "moving within" the threatened area. In 5e this is not the case.

Comment: Maybe if you had a *second* polearm, with which you had only 5' reach...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### A creature within your reach already cannot enter your reach.

To “enter” your reach, as required by Polearm Master, a creature must go from not being in your reach to being in your reach. This is what the word “enter” means. If a creature is already within your reach, and they move around within your reach, they have not entered your reach.

Comment: Too small for me to edit, but I assume `The “enter” you reach,` should be `To “enter” your reach,`.

Comment: Thanks, MJ713. Edited that. You could make an edit that small at *2,000 reputation.*